# Libtorrent speed being capped at 1 MB/s

Tags: c++, libtorrent, libtorrent-rasterbar

Hi I'm trying to develop a LibTorrent client based on the example client provided by the LibTorrent library(client_test.cpp) but I'm getting the strange behavior of being capped at 1 MB/s download and upload speed between machines. I've tried using the example client and changing all the settings to max, I've also tried using the client_test in high performance mode but I still get the speed cap. I know it's not a network issue as transferring a file between these machines over the network through Windows gives an average of ~100 MB/s. Could there be a setting I've been missing that's capped by default at 1 MB/s?

Comment: Given that we can't see what you've *done* how do you expect us to guess at what you *haven't* done?

Comment: one guess of what's happening is that bittorrent transfers the file in *random order*, causing disk seeks (i.e. perhaps your disk is the bottleneck). Presumably your comparison transfers the file sequentially. You could set your downloader to sequential download mode to test.

Answer (score 0):

"transferring a file between these machines over the network through Windows", that's not the same as using the torrent protocol that can be throttled by isp's.

To test simply try the same .torrent in utorrent on the same machine.